# Postman stuck on sending request whenever trying a to send a GET request to an API hosted locally

Tags: asp.net, api, postman, postman-native-app

I am trying to test an API hosted on a local IIS server on my pc using postman, however it gets stuck on sending request . Then after a long period of  time of sending request trial, it fails and says Could not get response. When checking log it comes up with read ECONNRESET on Error

here is the error on  the log

GET http://localhost:44368/weatherforecast
Error: read ECONNRESET
Request Headers
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.8
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 51f2fa9f-222a-4b9a-a84f-488423dd6aa6
Host: localhost:44368
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: never mind it was a url issue